# Show set $A = \{x : a<x<b\}$ contains neither its LUB nor GLB

Tags: real-analysis

Show set $A = \{x : a<x<b\}$

it seems obvious that $glb(A) = a\notin A$

and $lub(A) = b \notin A$

although I do not know what i am missing here.

Comment: What you say it's correct, but they probably want you to provide a more formal proof of this fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, the least upper bound $\sup A$ of $A$ and the greatest lower bound $\inf A$ of $A$ are not elements of $A$ and moreover, $a=\inf A$ and $b=\sup A.$ If you prove the latter then you are done. To prove it you can do the following:

Let $x<b.$ Since $\mathbb N$ is not bounded above there is some natural $N$ such that $1/(b-x)<N\iff x+1/N<b.$ Since $x<x+1/N$ we conclude that given any $x<b$ we will always find some largest number $y$ (in this case $y=x+1/N$) such that $x<y<b,$ which means that $x$ is not an upper bound of $A.$ Therefore every upper bound of $A$ must be $\geqslant b$ and since $b$ is an upper bound of $A$ we conclude that $b$ is the **least** upper bound of $A,$ that is $b=\sup A.$ 
 A similar argument can be used to prove that $a=\inf A.$

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to prove that $\sup(A)=b$ and $\inf(A)=a$. The way you do that is by assuming that there is a lower/higher upper/lower bound and arriving at a contradiction. Hint: use density.

Comment: density of rationals is not being introduced in kirkwood analysis.